# Report Builder output not grouping correctly

Tags: reporting-services, report, grouping, builder, subreport

I've tried to use a small dataset to get the results I want before applying the same idea with a larger dataset that involves more complex SQL queries in report builder to group the outputs.
The report outputs and groups the records correctly in the smaller dataset test report as shown below by region, however when I try it with a larger dataset with sql queries, it outputs like this.

I'm trying to understand how to get it where the region label(blue row) appears once without repeating just like it does in the smaller dataset report. I know I can remove the region row altogether to not have them repeat but I would like it to appear once so it can act as a cover sheet before printing each record out associated to that region just as it does in the smaller dataset. 

I've attached images of the reports along with the subreports as well as the output report files
Please let me know if I can supply anymore information to make it clearer 

[Larger Dataset Report with SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yilf2.png)

[Smaller Dataset Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4ihp.png)

[Larger Dataset Report Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOKhk.png)

I've also attached another version of the larger dataset report where I changed the parameter from wkreq_id to 'desk', hoping that by passing the region, the ID's would be grouped by the desk location

[Larger Dataset with desk parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM22n.png)